# Displaying customer bi-weekly from start date for this week in SQL

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to figure out how to start with this. So each customer should be display bi-weekly starting from the start date. I want the current week to display those that should be display for this week.

Here's my table.

```
Customers_Id(PK)|First|Last  |    Address   | Phone   | Start_Date  | Tech_Id (FK)  |
----------------+-----+------+--------------+---------+-------------+---------------+
     1          | Bob |Smith | 123 Fake St. | 3298492 |   8/4/2010  |     1         |
     2          | John|Man   | 123 Noe St.  | 2930482 |   4/15/2008 |     1         |
     3          | Tom |Lee   | 123 Polk St. | 9308523 |   6/21/2012 |     2         |
```

Hopefully this is clear enough.

Comment: which RDBMS are you using ? SQL Server, Oracle? also can you show us some sample output?

Comment: I'm in SQL Server.  I figure it out now.  This is what I have. `SELECT *
 FROM Customers
 Where DATEDIFF (ww, Start_Date, GETDATE())%2 = 0`

Answer (score 0):

in mysql, you can do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE WEEK(NOW())=WEEK(Start_Date)
```

Comment: Does this show each week or bi-weekly?  I'm having error that NOW is not a recognized built-in function name.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer I have.

`SELECT *
    FROM Customers
    Where DATEDIFF (ww, Start_Da, GETDATE())%2 = 0`